# How to connect Azure Key Vault to C# Windows Service with app.config

Tags: c#, azure, windows-services, azure-keyvault, connected-services

How do I connect Azure Key Vault to C# windows Service application using visual studio? I am using VS 2019 and .NET Framework 4.7.2.

There is no service dependencies option under connected service where I usually find Azure Key Vault for the Web services.

This is what it looks like for **Web services**
[image]

[image]

But no such options available for **Windows service**

Comment: Does Windows service supports Azure Key Vault? These windows services will be deployed on Azure Virtual machine. What type of projects in C# support Azure Key Vault?

Answer (score 0):

Try with these steps

**1.** choose **Add > Connected Service** .Click on **+**  The Connected Service page appears with services you can add to your project.

[image]

**2.**  choose **Azure Key Vault** and click **Next**.

[image]

**3.**  Select the **subscription** you want to use, and then choose a existing Key Vault and click **Finish**

[image]

For more details refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/vs-key-vault-add-connected-service)

Comment: The problem with windows service is that there is no **Service dependencies** option available (please refer to second image of the question).  It has **Service Reference** option which doesn't have key vault dependency.

Comment: I tried with using visual studio 2019 I am able to find Service dependencies option. Can you please try with modify Visual studio Or re-install Visual studio.

Comment: I am using Visual studio 2019 too. And I can see the Services dependencies option for **Web service** ( first image of the question). But, there is no such option (Service dependencies) for **Windows service** (Second Image of the question). Looks like you tried with web service which works for me too but Windows service did not work. Any idea ?